# Returning multiple matches but only till first occurrence of a pattern using PHP and RegEX

Tags: php, regex

I am having a dataset that looks like

```
I(0,123...789){
A(0,567...999){.......n=Marc.....}
B(2,655...265){..................}
C(3,993...333){..................}
M(8,635...254){.................;}
}
O(0,345...789){
A(0,567...999){.......n=Marc.....}
B(2,876...775){..................}
C(3,993...549){..................}
M(8,354...987){.................;}
}
I(0,987...764){
A(0,567...999){.......n=Marc.....}
B(2,543...265){..................}
C(7,998...933){..................}
M(8,645...284){.................;}
}
B(0,123...789){
.......
}
I(0,987...764){
A(0,567...999){.......n=John.....}
B(2,543...265){..................}
C(7,998...933){..................}
M(8,645...284){.................;}
}
```

I am trying to return all I "sections" so starting from "I" until the closing tag that comes after the ;} but only if the "I" section contains n=Marc.

So far I came with

```
^([I]\(.*\){.*n=Marc.*^[M]\(.*;}.)}
```

https://regex101.com/r/VSuZh5/1

However in some cases, when data has a pattern like

```
I(0,123...789){
A(0,567...999){.......n=Marc.....}
B(2,655...265){..................}
C(3,993...333){..................}
M(8,635...254){.................;}
}
O(0,345...789){
A(0,567...999){.......n=Marc.....}
B(2,876...775){..................}
C(3,993...549){..................}
M(8,354...987){.................;}
}
```

The regular expression returns both the I and O section. Is there a way to make sure it always return the I section?

- apologies for the dataset, it's huge and contains a lot of sensitive data which I can't make public.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option might be to match `I`, then match all the lines that do not start with `}` and match at least 1 line that contains `n=Marc`

```
^I\([^()]*\){(?:\R(?!}|.*n=Marc).*)*\R.*\bn=Marc\b.*(?:\R(?!}).*)*\R}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `I\([^()]*\){` Match `I` followed by `(...){`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\R(?!}|.*n=Marc)` Match unicode newline sequence, assert what is on the right is not `}` or that the line contains n=Marc
  - `.*` Match any char 0+ times
- `)*` close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `\R` Match unicode newline sequence
- `.*\bn=Marc\b.*` Match any char 0+ times and match `n=Marc` between word boundaries
- `(?:` non capturing group

  - `\R(?!}).*` Match newline sequence asserting what is on the right is not `}`
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `\R` Match newline sequence
- `}` Match closing `}`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/exMtk3/1)

Answer (score 2):

If I knew, the input was always be formatted like sample, would rather split into chunks at a closing `}` at start of line, followed by a newline if followed by an upper: [`^}\R(?=[A-Z])`](https://regex101.com/r/okPG63/1/).

Then find the items starting with `I` and containing `n=Marc` by use of [`preg_grep`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php).

```
$res = preg_grep('/^I.*n=Marc/s', preg_split('/^}\R(?=[A-Z])/m', $str));
```

[See PHP demo at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/8nJ0i)

In your pattern the `.*` can skip over undesired items resulting in unexpected matches.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that we want an expression to return the `O` section that has `n=Marc` in it, something similar to:

```
(?=O\()([\s\S]*?n=Marc[\s\S]*?;}\s*})
```

Or maybe:

```
(?=O\()([\s\S]*?n=Marc[\s\S]*?;})\s*}
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/zAiXaV/1/)

For `I` sections we'd simply change `O` to `I`:

```
(?=I\()([\s\S]*?n=Marc[\s\S]*?;})\s*}
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/6mokqg/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?=I\()([\s\S]*?n=Marc[\s\S]*?;})\s*}/m';
$str = 'I(0,123...789){
A(0,567...999){.......n=Marc.....}
B(2,655...265){..................}
C(3,993...333){..................}
M(8,635...254){.................;}
}
O(0,345...789){
A(0,567...999){.......n=Marc.....}
B(2,876...775){..................}
C(3,993...549){..................}
M(8,354...987){.................;}
}
I(0,987...764){
A(0,567...999){.......n=Marc.....}
B(2,543...265){..................}
C(7,998...933){..................}
M(8,645...284){.................;}
}
B(0,123...789){
.......
}
I(0,987...764){
A(0,567...999){.......n=John.....}
B(2,543...265){..................}
C(7,998...933){..................}
M(8,645...284){.................;}
}';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $key => $I) {
    echo $I[0] . "\n";
}
```

#### Output

```
I(0,123...789){
A(0,567...999){.......n=Marc.....}
B(2,655...265){..................}
C(3,993...333){..................}
M(8,635...254){.................;}
}
I(0,987...764){
A(0,567...999){.......n=Marc.....}
B(2,543...265){..................}
C(7,998...933){..................}
M(8,645...284){.................;}
}
```